# Connecting to Raspberry database with TCP/IP over SSH

Tags: ssh, mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to my raspberry MYSQL server with MySQL workbench over SSH but get the error:
"Could not connect the SSH Tunnel WARNING: Server public key has changed"
I´m not sure why since I can connect with SSH with PUTTY.

MySQL workbench connection settings:

SSH hostname = local ip of my raspbery:22

SSH username = username of my pi

SSH Password = password of my pi

SSH Key File = nothing (no clue what to put here)

MySQL hostname = localhost

MySQL server port = 3308 (set in my.cnf)

username = root

Password = password of root

Default Schema = mysql

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple devices on the same local subnet that you connect to, using SSH?

Your client saves public keys associated with IPs in the known_hosts file. The most likely cause is that another device was assigned to that IP and your client expects the previous ssh server (with a different public key, depending on how PuTTY was installed) to appear. If it happens just that one time (your ssh client should be updating its known_hosts file), there's nothing to worry about.

If the problem does persist, try renaming/editing/deleting the public_hosts file (or registry key), so that the old public key for that server is not used anymore:

```
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts
```

or

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SoftWare\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys
```

Make a backup just in case, either a copy of the file or a reg key export.

Comment: It´s sadly not a one time thing. I am totaly unable to connect with MySQL workbench. There should not be any other devices using that IP since its reserved in the router.

Comment: What kind of client are you using, on which OS and is this on your local network, and if so, how is this set up?

Comment: The dbms is MySQL workbench on my PC. The raspberry is runing debian OS 32-bit with MySQL server. SSH is enabled hence I can use PUTTY. I granted all priveleges to root on any ip. I have removed the ip-bind in my.cnf.

Comment: I'd try temporarily renaming (or deleting) the known_hosts file, then starting putty. Should probably be either here: C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts or here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SoftWare\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys (make a reg key backup!) depending on how you set up putty (regular, portable etc)

Comment: So I renamed the known_hosts file and connected to the Raspberry with putty. It worked. I can now connect with MySQL workbench! Thank you so much! I have no clue how/why that worked but I am verry grateful.

Comment: A new install means a new randomly generated public key, that'd be my main suspicion. Great to hear, I'll update my answer :)